# cant get CasperJS to work on Mac OSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, phantomjs, casperjs

Tried almost everything, ending up with removing all npm&node (and node modules) and installing again. same results:

```
CasperError: Can't find module fs

phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:297 in patchedRequire
phantomjs://platform/colorizer.js:35
CasperError: Can't find module fs

phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:297 in patchedRequire
phantomjs://platform/casper.js:36
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('casper').create()')

 phantomjs://code/cloner.js:1 in global code
:0 in injectJs
phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:435
```

It will even happen just by placing

```
 var casper = require("casper").create();
```

Any ideas guys?

(MacBook Air OSX El Capitan 10.11.6)

Comment: Why did you tag this with [node.js]? PhantomJS and CasperJS have nothing to do with node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Did you: `var fs = require('fs');` ?

Are casperjs and phamtomjs installed globally ?