# error while running casperjs code from shell comand in nodejs script

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I am getting following error when I try to execute shell command (casperjs delete.js) from nodejs script.

[image: Error]

Casperjs Script:
[image: Casperjs Script Start]

[image: Nodejs Script calling casperjs]

I tried to uninstall fs, but still I am getting same error. I am not using fs module in delete.js which has casperjs code.

Please help me sort this issue.

below is the test.js which is calling casper.js script:

[test.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj8um.png)

[Casperjs script, delete.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Qgy.png)

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Hmn.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the code, you know no of us have time to transcript your code.

Answer (score 0):

**CasperJS is not a node.js module**. It is a separate program that supports a common javascript paradigm but is incomaptible with node.js. If you want to use CasperJS, write a scrpt for it and run it from command-line like

```
casperjs script.js
```

If you want to create a script for node.js and use a headless browser in it, please see [phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom) module.

**Update:**

CasperJS script should use node.js modules because it it not based on node.js. So this line should be removed:

```
var fx = require('node-fixtures');
```

Comment: I have done samething, I have written casperjs script separately, file name delete.js, then I am trying to call this casper script from node with shelljs. This was working as expected before I was using fs module. As mentioned on 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508654/cant-get-casperjs-to-work-on-mac-osx' I tried to uninstall fs module, but I am still getting same error.

Comment: Please show your script, in the screenshot you provided there's nothing about `fs` module. Don't forget you cant use node.js modules in CasperJS either.

Comment: I have added few more screenshots in the question, running casperjs is a part of clearing test data, therefore I am running it after my test ends which are written using nodejs modules.

Comment: Tried removing that line, but still getting following error:  var fx = require('node-fixtures');  
 CasperError: Can't find module fs

  phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:307 in patchedRequire
  phantomjs://platform/colorizer.js:35
CasperError: Can't find module fs

  phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:307 in patchedRequire
  phantomjs://platform/casper.js:36
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'require('casper').create')

  phantomjs://code/deleteRecords.js:1 in global code
  :0 in injectJs
  phantomjs://code/bootstrap.js:456

Comment: Please add your current CasperJS code to the question as text.